# Remove items from a List which are in another List by a specific property?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have two lists:

ListA with CancelledFlights
ListB with all Flights

I would like to remove all CancelledFlights from ListB with all flights **compared not by the object but by the property FlightNumber**. How could I achieve this with Lambda or LINQ? I know how to select in LINQ and lambda but not how to remove ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use linq to do that

```
var cancelledFlightNumbers = ListA
    .Select(x => x.FlightNumber)
    .ToList();

var cancelledFlightsRemoved = ListB
    .Where(x => !cancelledFlightNumbers.Contains(x.FlightNumber))
    .ToList();
```

If you have too many items then you can use `HashSet` to improve performance

```
var cancelledFlightNumbers = new HashSet<int>(ListA.Select(x => x.FlightNumber));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I hope i understood it right: you are extracting only the FlightNumber Property of ListA to a new list to use this list to remove the Flights from the ListB? Is this really needed? I mean isnt it possible to use the list directly in the 2nd Query?

Comment: yes you are right, you can replace `cancelledFlightNumbers` with `ListA
    .Select(x => x.FlightNumber)` in second query.

Comment: If `ListA` is large it would possibly be worth creating a `HashSet<T>`, rather than `List<T>`. It would simply be `var cancelledFlightNumbers = new HashSet<int>(ListA.Select(x => x.FlightNumber));`.

Comment: If the lists are big, then you might want to wrap `cancelledFlightNumbers` with a `HashSet` so that you have an efficient solution.

Comment: @Yacoub: I have about >10.000 Items.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thanks for the hint. But i have an Object with multiple properties and only one property is really unique (the id property). Is it also possible to work with this "reduced" object property and ignore all the other properties?

Comment: @STORM - Yes. My suggestion creates a `HashSet<T>` of flight numbers only. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of to do that, one with LINQ, one simply with `List<T>`'s methods:

- The `List<T>` approach:

  `allFlights.RemoveAll(flight => 
      cancelledFlight.Any(cancelled => cancelled.FlightNumber == flight.FlightNumber);`
- The LINQ approach:

  `// an IEqualityComparer<T> that can compare objects by FlightNumber.
  var flightNumberComparer = new FlightNumberComparer(); 
  allFlights = allFlights.Except(cancelledFlights, flightNumberComparer).ToList();`

As you can see, for this simple scenario, `RemoveAll` is probably the simplest. It removes the items in-place on the original list rather than creating a new list, and will probably be easiest to write.

Remember that LINQ is a *query* language. It's not designed to have *remove* operations. At most, it can create a filtered view of a collection and create a *new* list based on that (like we did here). But LINQ, in itself, won't help you remove items from a list.